# Generatingfunctionology, why does nCk*y^n vanish when n is a negative integer?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

In Generatingfunctionology (2nd ed available free here https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html ), nCk for integer n < 0 is defined as

[nCk = n*(n-1)*...*(n-k+1)/k!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oOs6.jpg)

Then he asserts that:

[sum (nCk)*y^n with n ranging over all integers, k is an integer >= 0, summand vanishes whenever n < k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZl8S.jpg)

I see why the summand would vanish for nonnegative integer n < k, because n*(n-1)*...*(n-n)*...*(n-k+1) = 0, but why for negative integer n? The text hasn't been corrected in the third edition, so I guess it's not an error? Or is it because nCk = nC(n-k), so if n is negative and k nonnegative n - k is negative, and that makes nC(n-k) = 0? Then how is that consistent with the earlier claim that nCk is nonzero for negative n and nonnegative k?

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a typo; $\sum_{n} {n\choose k} y^n$ should be $\sum_{n\ge 0} {n\choose k} y^n$.

Comment: The OP wonders how to reconcile the two statements from the book, and I have provided an explanation which I believe correct.